# Angular Update 10.2 to 11

Tags: angular, angular10, angular11

I'm trying to update Angular in my project from version 10.2 to 11.0.
Running ng update:

```
  @angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1002.0 -> 0.1100.1     ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular
  @angular/cdk                       10.2.7 -> 11.0.0         ng update @angular/cdk
  @angular/cli                       10.2.0 -> 11.0.1         ng update @angular/cli
  @angular/core                      10.2.3 -> 11.0.0         ng update @angular/core
  @angular/material                  10.2.7 -> 11.0.0         ng update @angular/material
```

Unfortunately each package I tried to update fails. I tried with --force and --allowDirty flags.

@angular-cli

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.0.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build- 
angular@0.1100.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
```

@angular-devkit/build-angular

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.0.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
```

@angular/material

```
Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

@angular/cdk

```
Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.0.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build- 
angular@0.1100.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root project
```

UPDATE
After installing with specific order I managed to update, but now the NPM won't install giving this message:

```
Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root 
project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the root 
project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.0.0-next" from 
@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.1" from the 
root project
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem. For me the problem was that the code editor was open,

On closing the editor and running `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli` angular successfully updated

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem, tried different orders for upgrades, removed node_modules folder several times, and had still no luck.
For me, the problem was that I was using Node v15. I uninstalled it and re-installed Node v14 -> works

Comment: Can confirm. (1) Downgrade to Node 14. (2) npm install, so you have to correct package.lock. (3) Now run Angular upgrade from 10 to 11 and it works. (4) Switch back to node 15.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just delete node_modules, package-lock.json, and run  `npm install`, and everything is working now!

Answer (score 1):

In my case

- Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
- npm cache clean --force
- npm i  --force

I assume issue is after node upgrade to v14

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, i ended up using yarn package manager, and it resolved the issue.